# How to increase space between bottom and the first Y-Axis label and bottom chart's line?

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm using Chart.js to draw graphs and I have an issue:

I  would like to increase that distance, because now it looks inaccurately.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution:

```
xAxes: [{
       ticks: {
         padding: 10
       }
      }]
```